# Fitting logistic regression models

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, regression-analysis, logistic-regression

I am studying The Elements of Statistical Learning book and I have a question. On pages 120-121 the  logistic regression problems is rewritten in the form of  matrix and vectors products as follows:(4.21 transformed to 4.24).

[image]
[image]
We know $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{P+1}$, so based on definition on page 121 $X$ is a $N \times P+1$ matrix, and its columns contain $x_i$ and P is N-dimensional vector contains $p(x_i;\beta)$ in its $i^{th}$ element. When I followed this defenitions I get
$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{\ell}(\beta )} {\partial \beta} =   \left[  \begin{array} { c }
x_1^T   \\
  \vdots   \\ 
   x_n^T  
\end{array} \right ]  \left[  \begin{array} { c }
y_1 -p(x_1;\beta)   \\
  \vdots   \\ 
 y_n -  p(x_n;\beta) 
\end{array} \right ]
= X^T (y-p) $

I assumed what I wrote above is equivalent to (4.24). But when I multiplied them I don't see how 4.24 is  equivalent to 4.21.
I would appriciate if anyone could help to understand this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your mistake is that it is supposed to be that each $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ since it is logistic regression with intercept, which is why the the first component if each $x_i$ is $1$.  In other words, the sample size is $N$, the number of independent variables is $p$, and an intercept is also being assumed.  So $\mathbf{X}$ is the $N\times(p+1)$ data matrix ($N$ rows or observations and $p+1$ columns or variables plus intercept) and thus $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{p})$ makes sense in the book.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, I have not considered that first element in my writing but I don't see how it will change anything. Am I missing something? My problem is each $x_i$ is multiplied by $y_j$ and $p(x_j)$ that  $i \neq j$.

Comment: So your matrix equation is wrong.  The first matrix should be $\mathbf{X}^T=[x_1...x_N]$, where I'm assuming each $x_i$ is a column vector.  If each $x_i$ in the book are row vectors, then it should be $\mathbf{X}^T=[x_1^T...x_N^T]$, but I don't have the book in front of me.

Comment: According to the definition the $x_i$ s are column of $X$. I can update the $x_i$ to be $n+1$ -dimensional just I don't know what should be the first element of $y-p$. and even by adding this I don't see the relation between 4.24 and 4.21. For example in 4.24, $x_2$  will be multiplied by $y_3 - p(x_3)$. which is not correct.

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: Sorry I corrected  the dimension, that causes confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{p}$ is a $N$-dimensional column vector whose first entry is $y_1-p(x_1)$, which is a scalar (real number).  So 4.21 can be written as $p+1$ equations:
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{i=1}&[y_i-p(x_i)]\\
&\vdots\\
\sum^N_{i=1}&x_{i1}[y_i-p(x_i)]\\
&\vdots\\
\sum^N_{i=1}&x_{ip}[y_i-p(x_i)],
\end{align}
where we note that the first entry of each $x_i$ is 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $\bf X$ contains $x_i$ in its $i$th row. So the proper way to view $\bf X$ as a block matrix is
$$
{\bf X} = \left[\begin{matrix}
x_1^T\\
\vdots\\
x_N^T
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
and therefore
$$
{\bf X}^T=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1&\cdots&x_N\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Now you can properly multiply ${\bf X}^T$ and $y-p$ to obtain (4.21).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the definition by the book, $X$ columns contains $x_i$s.

Comment: @Crimson No, as stated $X$ has $N$ rows and $P+1$ columns. If what you are saying is true (i.e. if the columns of $X$ hold $x_i$s), then each $x_i$ would be $N$-dimensional and there would be $P+1$ of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was confused. Thanks.